# How to find nested element in Android Appium testing?

Tags: automation, appium, android-testing, appium-android

I am new to Appium. I searched the web and tried several ways, but nothing worked. Please find the code below:

```
driver.findElementByXPath("//android.widget.FrameLayout[1]/android.widget.FrameLayout[1]/android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.widget.RelativeLayout[@resource-id=\"in.dmart:id/linear_guide_view_skip\"]/android.widget.android.widget.TextView").click();
```

And

```
driver.findElementByXPath("//android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.widget.RelativeLayout[1]/android.widget.android.widget.TextView[1]").click();
```

And

```
driver.findElementByAndroidUIAutomator("text(\"GOT IT\")").click();
```

And

```
List<WebElement>textView=driver.findElements(By.className("android.widget.android.widget.TextView"));
for(i=0;i<textView.size();i++){    
if(textView.get(i).getText().equals("GOT IT"))
    textView.get(i).click()
}
```

Please find UIAutomator Viewer screenshot attached:

[image]

Server logs :

```
[debug] [W3C] Calling AppiumDriver.findElements() with args: ["class name","android.widget.android.widget.TextView","e75769f1-53cb-44f7-9094-988b73fbc7be"]
[debug] [BaseDriver] Valid locator strategies for this request: xpath, id, class name, accessibility id, -android uiautomator
[debug] [BaseDriver] Waiting up to 0 ms for condition
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] Sending command to android: {"cmd":"action","action":"find","params":{"strategy":"class name","selector":"android.widget.android.widget.TextView","context":"","multiple":true}}
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"action","action":"find","params":{"strategy":"class name","selector":"android.widget.android.widget.TextView","context":"","multiple":true}}
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got command of type ACTION
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got command action: find
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Finding 'android.widget.android.widget.TextView' using 'CLASS_NAME' with the contextId: '' multiple: true
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Using: UiSelector[CLASS=android.widget.android.widget.TextView]
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] getElements selector:UiSelector[CLASS=android.widget.android.widget.TextView]
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Element[] is null: (0)
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] getElements tmp selector:UiSelector[CLASS=android.widget.android.widget.TextView, INSTANCE=0]
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Failed to locate element. Clearing Accessibility cache and retrying.
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Finding 'android.widget.android.widget.TextView' using 'CLASS_NAME' with the contextId: '' multiple: true
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Using: UiSelector[CLASS=android.widget.android.widget.TextView]
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] getElements selector:UiSelector[CLASS=android.widget.android.widget.TextView]
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Element[] is null: (0)
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] getElements tmp selector:UiSelector[CLASS=android.widget.android.widget.TextView, INSTANCE=0]
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] Received command result from bootstrap
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Returning result: {"status":0,"value":[]}
[debug] [W3C] Responding to client with driver.findElements() result: []
[HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session/e75769f1-53cb-44f7-9094-988b73fbc7be/elements 200 13691 ms - 12
```

Answer (score 0):

By looking at the view hierarchy, to locate the TextView you don't need to worry about nested views.

You can try with `UiSelector()` from `UIAutomator` as an example below. Refer to UiSelector documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/uiautomator/UiSelector.html#text(java.lang.String)).

```
driver.findElementByAndroidUIAutomator("new UiSelector().text(\""+GOT IT+"\")").click();
```

**Update:**

Try casting `driver` with `AndroidDriver`.

`((AndroidDriver<MobileElement>)driver).findElementByAndroidUIAutomator("new UiSelector().text(\"GOT IT\")");`

Comment: error, An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters.

Comment: Which `driver` are you using? Make sure the `driver` is of type `AndroidDriver`. AppiumDriver cannot work with `AndroidUIAutomator`, it has to be `AndroidDriver`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this. Please edit className value if it is different as per your app.

1. get all elements of class name
2. Click where text is "GOT IT"

   ```
   List<WebElement>textView =
     driver.findElements(By.className("android.widget.TextView"));
   for(i=0;i<textView.size();i++){    
   if(textView.get(i).getText().equals("GOT IT"))
       textView.get(i).click()
   }
   ```

Comment: still no element found

Comment: Can u share screenshot clearly showing all properties of the element "TextView:GOTIT" in UIAutomatorViewer ? and appium server logs also if possible

Comment: Can you try now I have updated class name. Make sure sync issue should not be there. Use explicit wait and capability newCommandTimeOut=5000